# Emulation in Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I am wondering if I can emulate Ubuntu on Windows through VirtualBox, then emulate Windows on Ubuntu through VirtualBox.

My system specifications:

```
Processor: AMD Turion x2 2.3 Ghz
Memory: 2 Gb RAM
Video: ATI Radeon HD 3200 256 MB
```

Comment: yes, but why would you want to?

Comment: Nothing to do =)

Comment: As the answerer below indicates, this may not be possible in VirtualBox, although it is in VMWare.  The only reason I load VMWare in my virtual machine, is to check compatability with new versions of Ubuntu

Comment: I would think it's possible but it would be pretty slow. I haven't tried but I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you can emulate both Ubuntu on a Windows host, and Windows on an Ubunut host with Virtual Box there is at present no support for nested virtual machines (i.e. emulating Windows in an emulated Ubuntu on a Windows host).

Apart from a lack of support it would also mean a considerable drop in performance making it rater useless.